# Get the size of a nested array in C

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, data-structures

```
char* alanina[] = {"alanina", "GCA","GCC","CGC","GCU"};
char* arginina[] = {"arginina", "AGA","AGG","CGA","CGC","CGG","CGU"};
char **aminoacids[] = {alanina,arginina};

printf("%i\n",(int)(sizeof(aminoacids[0]) / sizeof(**aminoacids[0])));
```

// the console display 8 and the correct answer is 5.

Answer (score 2):

once you put your arrays in an array of pointers like this:

```
char **aminoacids[] = {alanina,arginina};
```

you decay them into simple pointers. and you get `sizeof(pointer)/sizeof(char)` => 8 on your 64-bit compiler because your `sizeof` division uses a double `**` as demominator instead of one (that's the second mistake)

If you did `sizeof(aminoacids[0]) / sizeof(*aminoacids[0])` you'd get 1 as a result, for the same reason: `aminoacids[0]` has decayed to a pointer.

The only way to get 5 is `sizeof(alanina)/sizeof(*alanina)` because the array has not decayed and the compiler can provide its storage size.

An alternate way of computing the number of elements would be to introduce a convention to `NULL` terminate your arrays. Then you'd just scan the array for `NULL` and get the size that way.

```
{"alanina", "GCA","GCC","CGC","GCU",NULL};
```